# Doing nothing within the ternery operator

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my nodeJS server I've got the following:

```
console.log(socket.geoData.hostname + socket.geoData.uri + ": " + 
                                socket.geoData.country + 
                                (socket.geoData.city != "false" ? ", " + socket.geoData.city : false)
                            );
```

But if condition fails it is actually appending the word false and not simply doing nothing.  In PHP, I could return false and nothing would be appended.  How can I achieve that here?

Comment: is city "false" actually `string` or `boolean` ?

Comment: I don't know the order of operations for the ternery operator relative to the != "False" statement so you may wish to add a parenthesis to make it explicit. Also, why not just say "" instead of false?

Comment: I just found one answer as per your question asked answered by @fra9001[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960619/javascript-ternary-operator-with-empty-else/31960809]

Answer (score 2):

Just return empty string (`""`) instead of `false`

Comment: Dammit, why didnt I think of that.  Sorry.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could take an empty string as value.

```
console.log(socket.geoData.hostname + socket.geoData.uri + ": " +
  socket.geoData.country +
  (socket.geoData.city != "false" ? ", " + socket.geoData.city : "")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the code in a if, who checks if the `socket.getData.city` is != false, before do anything

```js
if(socket.geoData.city !== "false") {
    console.log(`${socket.geoData.hostname}@${socket.geoData.uri}:`);
    console.log(`${socket.geoData.country} - ${socket.geoData.city}`);
}
```