# Javascript ternary operator: what to put as the false option when none is required?

Tags: javascript, default-value, conditional-operator

with an if/else block, else can be omitted when nothing needs doing if the 'if' is not true.

e.g.:

```
If (A) {
B;
}
// works perfectly well;
```

When using the ternary operator though, an empty 'else' option throws an error.

e.g.

```
(A) ? B :  // throws error

(A) ? B // throws error
```

Putting null as the else option stops the error and seems to work fine but is it safe? Alternatively, what is the correct way to use a ternary statement when there is no need for the 'else' part?

e.g.

```
(A) ? B : null ; // no error but is it safe or is there a better alternative?
```

Comment: If there's no `else` then just use a plain old `if` instead of a construct that has an `if` _and_ `else`...

Comment: The ternary conditional operator is not a drop-in replacement for an if/else structure.  They're two different things.  The ternary conditional operator is meant to evaluate to a value based on a condition.  If you're not observing a result of the operator then (1) it doesn't matter if that result is `null` and (2) you're probably using the wrong structure.  If you want to perform an operation based on a condition, `if` was designed exactly for that purpose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Ternary operator with empty else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960619/javascript-ternary-operator-with-empty-else)

Comment: @jvilhena - it should do but frankly, no as the answers are complicated and overlook the simple answer given by ssb below (which I'd overlooked as a superior alternative). Also, I searched for quite a while and that one didn't feature. I suppose the question is so close that mine may be deleted but I hope not as the simple answer is very pleasing but has passed me by for ages! Thanks.

Comment: @David that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if` on a single line if you want as well.

```
if (a) b;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's more pleasing than having to specify null.

Comment: Makes me think of https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html, I tend to make brackets mandatory personally.

Comment: I'm not necessarily endorsing this as the best stylistically, but it is at the least debatable and in common use.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND) instead.

```
a && b;
```

**But if you do not need the result of the expression stay with standard [`if` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).**